# How to merge two .PO wordpress language files?

Tags: wordpress, translation

I have a **.po** file in Wordpress that works with the theme and it contains **1259 characters**, and i translated many words in it manually.

That been said, after the theme was updated i found out that the new .po files contains **1898 (460 more characters).**

So i would like to know if there is a safe and efficient way to merge these two files, that means keeping the integrity of manual translations i did + the new terms that were added by new version of the theme file.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Use Poedit to sync your translation file and be done with it?

Comment: It did solve the issue. Thank you so much :D